# Can't download file in IE7 but there isn't any issue in Firefox, Chrome, etc..?

Tags: php, internet-explorer-7, download

I have an script that receives an encrypted url and from that generates a download, the most critic par of the script is this:

```
$MimeType = new MimeType();
$mimetype = $MimeType->getType($filename);
$basename = basename($filename);
header("Content-type: $mimetype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$basename\"");
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
if ( @readfile($filename)===false ) {
  header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
  loadErrorPage('500');
}
```

Downloads works as charm in any Browser except IE, I have seen problems related to 'no-cache' headers but I don't send anything like that, they talk about utf-8 characters, but there is not any `utf-8 characters`(and the $filename has not any utf-8 characteres neither).

Comment: "It works except in IE" is not helpful at all.  How does it not work?  Is there an error message?  A timeout?  Does it display the file contents?  Does it download the wrong thing?

Comment: timeout basically, it pops out a download window but never advance, after a couuple of minutes it timeouts saying: "Internet Explorer Cannot Download FileName from WebServer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://bytes.com/forum/thread554529.html) has a problem similar to yours in IE6. To summarize:

> session_start() by default sends a cache control header including "no-store".
>   Internet Explorer takes this a bit too literally, but doesn't have appropriate
>   error handling for the case, and as a result explodes cryptically when you
>   attempt to save the output page to disk.
>
> Before session_start(), add "session_cache_limiter('none');", or look up that
>   function and tweak the limiter as appropriate (probably 'private' is closer to
>   the mark).

I realize the code snippet you posted does not include a call to `session_start();`, but I figured I'd share this possible solution in case you do have a call to it and just didn't show us.

Comment: Yes there is a sessions_start() above all, i just post that code because is a very long code.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by sending the headers

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

I didn't knew that session_start() send headers by it's own.

I found the answer in the comments section of: [Error: Internet Explorer Cannot Download FileName from WebServer](http://www.alagad.com/go/blog-entry/error-internet-explorer-cannot-download-filename-from-webserver)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

In IE7 Browser go to internet option--> security--->custom level --->downloads 
then enabled autometic prompting for file download.

this will solve the problem.

hope this will help

Comment: You can't really ask all your users to do the same :)